# nginx (port 8000) alongside apache (port 80): requests timing out

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

On a Ubuntu 14.04 server, I'm considering switching to nginx in replacement of apache and need both to run alongside while i'm getting myself more familiar with nginx. Therefore I'm setting nginx to listen to port 8000, whilst apache listens to 80 to serve the existing sites.

Installation went fine ( `apt install nginx`). I've configured a simple domain with this configuration

```
server {

    listen   8000;
    listen   [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/user/www/domain.eu/public;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.eu;

}
```

However, when I test a request to http://domain.eu:8000 it times out.

`netstat -lnp | grep 80`  shows that the configuration seems to be correct AFAICS:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22195/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      22195/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17204/apache2
udp6       0      0 fe80::216:3eff:fe16:123 :::*                                27688/ntpd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3580     1984/master         private/mailman
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8089621  1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4807     2179/python         /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
```

`curl -v http://domain.eu:8000` outputs:

```
*   Trying 1XX.2X.12X.2X5...
* connect to 1XX.2X.12X.2X5 port 8000 failed: Operation timed out
```

`nginx -t` says its configuration is fine.

I've restarted nginx, i've stopped then started it multiple times.

What am I missing ?

---

**UPDATE 1: firewall**

Also disabled ufw and fail2ban, stopped and started nginx, still connexion timed out.

---

**UPDATE 2: localhost**

`curl -I localhost:8000` from the same machine returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 26 Nov 2016 22:03:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 15
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 21:01:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55808eb5-f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

---

**UPDATE 3: port 80**

I have set nginx to port 80 and shut down apache. Nginx then is able to serve the request as expected.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking incoming connections in port 8000

Comment: @vikelidisKostas sorry, I forgot to mention that. Also disabled ufw and fail2ban. No improvement.

Comment: On the nginx server what is the result of : curl -I localhost:8000 Just to make sure the server is up & running. What type of server are you using ?

Comment: I've updated my reply. In short: it works as intended.

Comment: Based on your description, it's almost certainly a firewall. You should check the firewalls _external_ to your virtual machine.

Comment: Can you please post the results of iptables -L command?